# retrieving an image uploaded image of html form using python cgi

Tags: image

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cgi
import os
from http.cookies import*

import sqlite3
path= '/var/www/html/bb.db'
con=sqlite3.connect(path)
cur=con.cursor()


form=cgi.FieldStorage()

print("Content-Type:text/html\n\n")
print(
      """
    <html>
      <body>
       <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="get">
        <select name="drop" >
          <option>5star</option>
          <option>Munch</option>
          <option>cadbury</option>
          <option>Kurkure</option>
        </select>
        <br>
         <input type="file" name="preview" accept="image/*" >
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>""")



a=form.getvalue('drop')
b=form.getvalue('preview')
if 'submit' in form and a!=None :

    cur.execute("drop table images")
    cur.execute("create table images(img blob)")
    cur.execute("insert into table values(?)",(codecs.encode(form.getvalue('preview'))))

    print("""
    <p><img src=""")
    cur.execute("select * from images")
    data=cur.fetchall()
    print(codecs.decode(i[0][0]))
    print("""alt="hii" style="width:320px;height:320px;border:0;"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
    """)
```

i am trying to retrieve an image uploaded in html form with python cgi ...
but this code isn't working ,....please do help me out with the code ..
thanks in advance ... 
actually i also used enctype in the above form ...but its of no use ...